# Where's solaris 11 's pkg install package downloaded path?

Tags: io, solaris, iostat

I use `pkg install gcc-3` in solaris 11 to install gcc 3. Where did `pkg` store the downloaded package install files / gcc-3.pkg file?

I tried `/etc/pkg/`, only get some useless mako file there.

I can see the `pkg` thread downloading the file, is there any way to monitor I/O status in solaris and get the path the pkg process is writing to? `iostat` seems only give the io rate and not the actually path.

Answer (score 1):

It caches downloaded files under /var/pkg but the exact paths are usually hashes and not generally useful.   It doesn't download a complete copy of the package, but only the files you need that aren't already located or cached on the system, so that upgrades to new versions are usually much faster, because they only download changed files.